# Converting list of integers into bytes in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, byte

I am converting the following set of integers into bytes, for passing to through a socket to a target IP address:

```
data = bytes([4,1,0,0,0,0, 224 + 53 // 16, 53 % 16])
```

However, the output I get for this is:

```
[4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 227, 5]
```

This is not what I was expecting. The syntax as above I believe may relate to Python 3 only. Can someone please advise how to amend to get a valid byte output?

Thanks

Comment: What were you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7 didnt have a `bytes()` built-in, it had [`bytearray()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
>>> bytearray([4,1,0,0,0,0, 224 + 53 // 16, 53 % 16])
bytearray(b'\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe3\x05')
```

Comment: Well, it does have a "bytes" but it's just an alias to `str`, which is not helpful.